# Why javafx application .jar dosen't work on OS MAC?

Tags: java, macos, javafx

I've build my very first .jar application and it works fine one windows machines but when I've tried to run it on Mac OS it throws java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException.

What may cause that?

Comment: are u using awt from JavaFX?

Comment: Yes, but only use Dimension class.

Comment: Can you show the full stack trace?

Comment: http://imgur.com/segboDG

http://imgur.com/gWfkWIq

Also i removed all references to awt lib.

Comment: Supply an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: It seems from your StackTrace that you are using JOptionPane, I'd recommend using a JavaFX equivalent such as [ConstrolsFX Dialogs](http://controlsfx.bitbucket.org/org/controlsfx/dialog/Dialogs.html) or the Alert class built into Java8u40.